# Why does Google+ bar show different data in Firefox and Safari?

Tags: gmail, google-plus

I use GMail in both office and home where I use Firefox and Safari respectively.

I see Reader in the list in Firefox

[image: Google bar]

but not in Safari. I need to select from the dropdown list.

Is there a way I can get my selected list of items in the Google+ bar in both Safari and Firefox ?

Comment: Its been a while since the Google Bar has disappeared. I think the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Could try spoofing your useragent for one of the websites. Just depends on how & why Google are changing it. It might not work properly in one of the browsers.

A user agent switcher plugin for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/